# Open source plugin for a tile layout similar to dynamit.us?

Tags: javascript, css, layout

I've stumbled upon this great website layout, and would like to use a layouting similar to this.
http://dynamit.us/

Comment: can't you make it? The HTML is quite straightforward, the images effect is pretty simple jQuery. I'm not sure about the backend, though, but it doesn't seem rocket science either. Maybe if you define "layout" you'll get better answers (are you talking about the design or about the CMS?)

Comment: Why do people think "rocket science" is hard? The physics behind it almost as simple as physics can be...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reference these jquery plugin, but just a css layout, without backpage.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

http://masonry.desandro.com/